# Creating time schedule from list of people and who they have to meet

Tags: python

I have a list of people ID and who they should meet as follows:

```
people = [
    [1, [2,3,4]], 
    [2, [1,3,4]], 
    [3, [1,2,4]],
    [4, [1,2,3]]
]
#    ^ person_id
#        ^ list of person to meet
```

I want to schedule the list so that each person meet at the different timeslot i.e. the output I would like to have is

```
people = [
    [1, [2,3,4]], 
    [2, [1,4,3]], 
    [3, [4,1,2]],
    [4, [3,2,1]]
]
#        ^ ^ ^  timeslot 1,2,3
```

This means that `1` has to meet `2` and `3` has to meet `4` in the first timeslot. ...

For the small number of people, I can do it by hand. I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this when I have a larger list. I attach the CSV file on larger people ID and who they have to meet [here](https://gist.github.com/titipata/9c43e3d435d2efb59e394d146e5998e5).

**Note** not sure if this is suitable for Stack Overflow, I can ask somewhere else. feel free to suggest.

Comment: This is suitable for stack overflow.

Comment: Is the data symmetric? E.g., can a dozen people **need** to meet person 4, while person 4 only needs to meet one person? In such a case, do you want to make the union or intersection of all meetings happen (or something else)?

Comment: @HansMusgrave Yes, it's symmetric >> everyone should meet everyone k times. I produced the matching through linear programming. I attach the CSV file for the sample dataset that I have in my question if you want to try out. Let me know if you have more question/ clarification!

Comment: @titipata That looks good. I was just curious if a simple solution would work fine or if more care needed to be taken. This reminds me of some graph handshake algorithms. I'm away from home and my library, but I'll see what google turns up.

Comment: @HansMusgrave a simple solution or the algorithm would be great! I'm trying to implement and cannot wrap my head quite well how to solve this problem.

Comment: @titipata I don't think it's trivial, but if you can accept an additional dependency most of the hard work has been done by other people. I'm coding up a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** for better clarity in case anyone stumbles here from Google. The content is nearly identical.

The way your data is set up, each meeting "belongs" in some sense to an individual. Take person 1 for example, they need meetings with persons 2, 3, and 4. This forces meetings for those people even if persons 2-4 do not have those meetings reflected in their meeting lists. In other words, there is a **symmetry** so that if there is a meeting between person 1 and person 2, there is also a meeting between person 2 and person 1. Any time a problem naturally has objects of interest (people) and a symmetric relationship between them (meetings), a **graph** is probably going to be an effective tool for solving the problem. In your case, you have the following graph.

[image: graph translation of problem]

Restating your problem in terms of this graph, you want a way to break up those meetings into groups so that in any group, the same person isn't in two meetings at once. This is commonly called an **edge coloring** of the graph, where you're labeling each of those groups with a so-called "color" and attempting to color each edge so that no vertex has two neighboring edges of the same color. In your problem, the solution you gave would be represented as follows.

[image: graph translation of solution]

Relevant information includes something called Vizing's Theorem. If the maximum number of meetings a single person has is N, then you either need N or N+1 different colors (different time slots) to solve your problem. Of course extra time slots could work fine, but usually you want a minimal solution. In your problem the solution you gave is clearly minimal. In general you might have time slots that are unoccupied for some individuals.

In practice, achieving the bound is NP-complete. There are various heuristic algorithms that usually do a good job and come close. The `networkx` library (which I love by the way) doesn't actually support edge colorings I don't believe, but an equivalent construct is the vertex coloring of a graph's line graph. The line graph is what you get when you turn all the edges into vertices and say that two such vertices are connected by an edge if they were formerly edges connected by a vertex. The line graph for your problem isn't too complicated.

[image: line graph of problem]

When looking at the line graph instead of the original, you instead want to find a **vertex coloring**, since now the vertices are the meetings (which you still want to allocate), and the edges represent being connected by a single person who can't be in two meetings at once. For your problem, the solution you gave is the following vertex coloring of the line graph.

[image: line graph of solution]

The whole point of going through this exercise in graph theory is that graph algorithms are well studied and well understood. The following code turns your data structure into a graph, uses the `networkx` library to find our vertex coloring of the line graph, and reformats the data into the structure you requested.

```
import networkx as nx

def build_line_graph(people):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(((p, q) for p, L in people for q in L))
    return nx.line_graph(G)

def color_graph(G):
    return nx.greedy_color(G)

def format_answer(coloring):
    res = {}
    N = max(coloring.values()) + 1
    for meeting in coloring:
        time_slot = coloring[meeting]
        for meeting_member in (0, 1):
            if meeting[meeting_member] not in res:
                res[meeting[meeting_member]] = [None] * N
            res[meeting[meeting_member]][time_slot] = meeting[1-meeting_member]
    return res

def nest_answer(people, formatted):
    return [[p, formatted[p]] for p, v in people]

>>> format_answer(color_graph(build_line_graph(people)))
{1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 4, 3], 3: [4, 1, 2], 4: [3, 2, 1]}

>>> nest_answer(people, format_answer(color_graph(build_line_graph(people))))
[[1, [2, 3, 4]], [2, [1, 4, 3]], [3, [4, 1, 2]], [4, [3, 2, 1]]]
```

I like the dictionary answer better for a few reasons, but we can reformat it to give the exact answer you requested with minimal effort.

One point I should mention is that your question does not have a unique correct answer. Any permutation of the time slots from a valid answer is also a valid answer, and often there are many other kinds of colorings which satisfy your requisite properties. Moreover, the greedy algorithm isn't guaranteed to yield an optimal solution (and in fact has pathologically bad counter-examples), but in this case it actually yields the same solution you came up with. Usually the solution will be quite good.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple (but probably suboptimal) solution:

```
people = [
    [1, [2,3,4]],
    [2, [1,3,4]],
    [3, [1,2,4]],
    [4, [1,2,3]]
]
meetings = set(tuple(sorted([meeter, meetee]))
               for meeter, meetees in people for meetee in meetees)

current = []
schedule = []
busy = set()
while meetings:
    for meeting in meetings:
        meeter, meetee = meeting
        if meeter in busy or meetee in busy:
            continue
        current.append(meeting)
        meetings.remove(meeting)
        busy.add(meeter)
        busy.add(meetee)
        break
    else:
        schedule.append(current)
        current = []
        busy = set()
if current:
    schedule.append(current)

num_slots = len(schedule)
personal_schedule = {meeter: [None] * num_slots for meeter, meetees in people}
for slot_index, slot in enumerate(schedule):
    for meeting in slot:
        meeter, meetee = meeting
        personal_schedule[meeter][slot_index] = meetee
        personal_schedule[meetee][slot_index] = meeter
personal_schedule = [list(items) for items in personal_schedule.items()]
print(personal_schedule)
```

First construct the list of all meetings. Then we try to stuff as many meetings in the current timeslot such that none of the people in that meeting are already busy in that timeslot. When we can't find such a meeting any more, we move onto the next timeslot. At the end, transform the meeting schedule into the personal schedule format as asked in OP.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan, this works perfectly. I'll check the solution in detail and accept by tomorrow!